# How to use conditional expressions inside of a numpy sum

Tags: python, numpy

I have an a 2d array where rows represent patients and the columns represent attribute (old, excercises, disease).

My intention is to count the number of patients who excercise and have disease. I know that it is possible to 
    np.sum(patientData[1])

but how can i do something like this
    np.sum(patientData[1] and patientData[2])

Example of data

```
A = [ [34, 1, 1],
      [22, 0, 0],
      [90, 1, 1]
    ]
```

So for example, first entry means the patient is 34 years old, excercises, and has the disease

The number of patients from this example who both excercise and have the disease is 2.

Right now I am doing this

```
excerciseAndDisease = 0
for row in A:
   if row[1] and row[2]:
      excercsieAndDisease += 1
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the formatting of the data contained in those arrays? (what datatypes)

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vectorized `&` instead of *and*, and index the columns with `[:,1]` and `[:,2]` if you have a numpy array:

```
np.sum(patientData[:,1] & patientData[:,2])
```

---

```
A = [[34, 1, 1],
     [22, 0, 0],
     [90, 1, 1]]
​
a = np.asarray(A)
np.sum(a[:,1] & a[:,2])
# 2
```

---

Or use `np.count_nonzero`:

```
%timeit np.sum(a[:,1] & a[:,2])
# 4.25 µs ± 10.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.count_nonzero(a[:,1] & a[:,2])
# 2.01 µs ± 23.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: np.sum(trainPatient[:,1] > 55 & trainPatient[: , 2] == 1) gives me "value error: truth value of an array with more than one element is ambigious"

Comment: If you have expressions, you need parenthesis around the expressions. `np.sum((trainPatient[:,1] > 55) & (trainPatient[: , 2] == 1))`. Since `&` has a higher precedence than `>` and `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try to use:

```
In [0]: a = np.array([-1,0,1,2,3,4,5])

In [1]: a[a<0]

Out[2]: array([-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy function assuming that second and third column is binary:

`numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(A[:,1], aa[:,2]))`